# $\sigma$-algebra of a function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I'm thinking about an example of a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal {F},\mathbb {P})$, a random variable $X$ and a function $f$ such that $\sigma(f(X))$ is strictly smaller than $\sigma(X)$ but $\sigma(f(X))\neq \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$. Also a function $g$ such that $\sigma(g(X))=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$. I think finite sample space might work but I'm not sure.

Comment: $X=\{1,2,3\} $ with the power set, $X(i)=i$ for all $i$, $f(1)=f(3)=1$ and $f(2)=2$ for the first one. $g\equiv 0$ for the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Take $\Omega =(0,1)$, $\mathcal F$ being the Borel $\sigma -$algebra and $\mathbb P$ the Lebesgue measure. Then $\sigma (X^2)\subsetneq\sigma (X).$

For your other question, if $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is any constant, then $\sigma (g(X))=\{\Omega ,\varnothing \}$.